# C++ Linker Error SDL Image - could not read symbols

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

I'm trying to use the SDL_Image library and I've added the .so to the link libraries list for my project (I'm using Code::Blocks, by the way).

After doing this, when I go to compile, I get this error:

```
Linking console executable: bin/Debug/ttfx
/usr/lib32/libSDL_image-1.2.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
```

What does this mean and how can I get it working?

Edit: I'm using gcc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the linking step there are incompatibilities since some of your object files were compiled for 32-bit and some for 64-bit. Looking at its path `libSDL_image.so` was probably compiled for 32-bit.

If you use the GNU compiler add `-m32` to your `CXXFLAGS` to compile your objects for 32-bit, too.

Comment: How exactly would I add that to my CXXFLAGS? Would it be near where I added that file to my link libraries list?

Comment: @Matt: I don't use `codeblocks` myself, but this section in the docs seems to detail what one needs to do http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Developing_32_bit_apps_under_64_bit_Linux_(Ubuntu)#Setting_the_build_options_in_Code::Blocks

Comment: @MatthewH did you found out how to add it to the CXXFLAGS? Can you pls tell me how it is done?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/usrliblibfontconfig.so-could-not-read-symbols-file-in-wrong-format-488347/) and [this one](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/fedora-7-64bit-usrliblibexpat.so-could-not-read-symbols-file-in-wrong-format-563541/) suggest that the problem is you're doing a 64-bit compile with a 32-bit library. YMMV