# Compile shared library with link to other .so

Tags: c, gcc, g++, shared-libraries

I want to link an existing shared library (FlashRuntimeExtensions.so) to my C-code while compiling my own shared library. But whatever I try I always get the same error; that the file is in a wrong format. Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Here is my compile command:

```
$ g++ -Wall ane.c FlashRuntimeExtensions.so -o aneObject
FlashRuntimeExtensions.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld gaf exit-status 1 terug
```

Comment: `$ file FlashRuntimeExtensions.so` what's the output of this command ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527780/c-linker-error-sdl-image-could-not-read-symbols

Comment: @SirDarius: FlashRuntimeExtensions.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Comment: Are you (cross)compiling for ARM?

Comment: @tsurko Yes but I am not sure about the cross-compiling. I just want to compile a shared library that can be used on Android devices.

Comment: If it is for Android devices it won't work on your linux workstation - the architectures are different. Is this the case?

Comment: It doesn't have to work on my linux installation. the c code is purely meant to be used on android devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line tries to generate x86 code and link it to ARM code using the native g++ available in your distribution.

This will not work. Use the Android NDK available here: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

> The NDK includes a set of cross-toolchains (compilers, linkers, etc..) that can generate native ARM binaries on Linux, OS X, and Windows (with Cygwin) platforms.

Answer (score 0):

In general `.so` will be linked using `-l`.

for example, pthread `-lpthread` we use.

`gcc sample.c -o myoutput -lpthread`

But as per @chill's statement, what you are doing in command is correct only.

I suggest you to refer the following link.

[C++ Linker Error SDL Image - could not read symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527780/c-linker-error-sdl-image-could-not-read-symbols)

Comment: The OP command line by itself is perfectly OK. There's no such requirement to link libraries (shared or not) only using `-l` option.

Comment: Hmm when I try that it gives me the error that it can not find the specified library, even if I specify the path with the -L option.. But it could be a compatibility problem reading from the link.

Comment: When I try to compile it as a 32 bit library with the -m32 option the result is not different from the previous result

Answer (score 0):

It should be an architecture mismatch. I faced this problem once, I have solved it by building the libs in same target platform and it is obvious. If you are using linux or Unix like OS you can see that by file command and if you are using windows you can see that using Dependency Walker. You need to make sure that all the libs matches architecture.